# May this is true :if $ a<b :\frac{a+c}{b+c} >\frac{a}{b} $ with $b,c>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Really i'm confused how do I show this if it is true ,let   $ a,b$ and $c$ be real numbers with $b,c >0$  if $ a<b   $ then:
$$\displaystyle \frac{a+c}{b+c} >\frac{a}{b} $$.

**Note**:I got this inequality from my student ,my guess is that is not true because :
$\displaystyle \frac{a+c}{b+c}>\frac{a}{b} \Leftrightarrow bc>ac$

And $\displaystyle 1>\frac{a+c}{b+c} \Leftrightarrow b+c>a+c$ .

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since $b$ and $c$ are positive, we have
$$
\frac{a+c}{b+c}>\frac ab \iff (a+c)b > a(b+c)
$$
I think you will find the second expression a bit easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
a<b&\implies ac<bc\\
&\implies ac+ab<bc+ab\\
&\implies a(b+c)<b(a+c)\\
&\implies  \frac{a}{b}<\frac{a+c}{b+c}
\end{align}

since $b,c>0$.

Comment: It holds even if $a$ is negative.

Comment: I don't  know where is the problem in my Note in the above  in My question ?

Comment: You don't need the line before the last, in your question.